# Listar checkbox selecionados

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a uma função, como eu faço para apresentar os valores selecionados dos checkbox e combobox em tempo real? Por exemplo, se eu selecionar a opção 1 do combobox e uma opção de checkbox as duas aparecem em formato de lista.

Ex:

Lista
Opção 01 - Combobox
Opção 01 - Checkbox

Comment: Poste o código que desenvolveu até aqui para receber mais ajuda!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando Javascript. Cria uma função que será executada sempre que alterar o valor, na função você pode escrever no consolo usando console.log() ou colocar num alert() ou ainda escrever no html $("#div").innerHtml(). Ficaria algo similar a isso:

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#combo').on('change', function (e) {
        var opcaoSelecionada = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        alert(valueSelected);
    });
});
</script>`